# Manager wants to me to change methodoloy for no good reason and I don't accept it, so we will have a meeting about it. How should I proceed?

Tags: manager, teamwork, leadership, conflict-resolution

I work in a small/medium startup (20 to 30 people) as a software developer. In this company there are 3 teams that kinda overlap with each other in the sense they all work with the same tech stack, they use and reuse each other's work more often and collaborate more. My team is comprised of 1 person : me . It's an entire new department and I'm the lead developer working on a total different tech stack. I have my direct team leader, but he's more of a Product Chief for the entire company and coordinates with all other teams and sales, so I'm basically the team lead and he's usually unavailable. There's an implicit rule in the air among us that "I take the lead and have the freedom to do so when taking technical decisions"

As in every company, we try to have processes in places. Specific tool for documentation, for repos, where to save files, etc etc. As a rule of thumb we all use Tool A (hidden names just for safety), and when I joined I was also using it.

For 5 months I used Tool A mainly for the sake of the process...it was me and the crickets...nobody there to ever login in the board or write anything. I did use another kanban/agile tool in my previous company and I decided...you know what, I will just continue using that one (Tool B), because it does suits my needs and make me more productive. There's no point in using Tool A if there's no one else using with me and the very little collaboration existing between my team and others are limited to a few sync meetings and slack talks.

So then I took the liberty to switch, also because I was told teams could work in an independent matter. For 2 months I kept using Tool B.

For one sprint, I wanted to share the board with the manager (not my direct manager/PC guy) to have his opinions on which task to prioritise.

This guy is always the one booking pointless meetings (imo) with usually at least 5 people, with always a chance of someone unrelated to be involved, creating discussions on Slack about stuff that we can probably only take a look in 3 months time an such. And he's a process freak. About 80% of the content of meetings I have to join organized by him are later dropped/forgotten because guess what : they don't matter. So yeah...at this point Im skeptical on the validity of whatever problem he tries to create

Then of course, after seeing my board on a different tool he was like " hey man, it's okay for now to use it...but I think soon enough we'll need to move your stuff from Tool B to Tool A. I kinda dismissed him, hoping he'd soon be focused on another useless endeavour, but 2 weeks after here he is, saying we should book a meeting (me him and 2 more people ofc!) to discuss how to proceed on doing that migration.

I could not keep quiet, cause that's not me...if something doesn't make sense I confront it, even if it might cost me the job...screw it. Told him this was a waste of time. Asked when there was ever a time that me using Tool B compromised collaboration or the work on other team, that would justify the transition. He didn't really have a convincing answer to it. In summary, he wants me to change to fit in in the model "one hat fits them all" that he so adore and we know it all boils down to the " I'm the manager that makes decision and you do it as I say"

The thing is...as I said, I have no problem in following orders, as long as it is something that makes sense. If I just have to do something because you're telling me to, that's not a good reason and I might end up leaving because doing nonsense just affects my overall daily satisfaction. I believe as a manager you need to proper backup your decisions to your team rather than a simple "because that's how we do things here". And also, the issue is not with Tool A. Yes..I prefer the other one, but I already worked with Tool A and Im comfortable using that as well and if it has to be done then so be it. The issue here is more the psychological effect on doing something because some guy has a lot of free time to be inventing problems and in my experience we shouldn't cultivate such behaviour and culture.

My reasoning is that if I give him a hard time in accepting some nonsense task he's giving, he'll think twice about coming to me with another task, just because of the sake of giving me a task. Mind you he's not my direct manager, so he does not really have the power to fire me, but even if he had I'd still not be worried about it.

I try to have his perspective on things too: it's hard to understand what's going on when you have to manage several people and they start to take independent decisions. Doing this is something that might give him a sense of control and peace of mind and avoid future problems although he doesn't know of now which problem are those? But as in any relationship I believe you need to trust the people you're dealing with, and that is true for working relationships too. If I feel this would compromise collaboration between the teams I wouldn't have chosen it and he should trust me on that decision, that's all.

Ironically, we are only having this future meeting and talking about this "issue"  because I did tell/showed him Im using a second tool, which I didn't even have to. If I haven't said anything I'd still be using the tool, doing my work just fine while he does his and work life would continue as normal...

Now, why I'm posting this is that I would like to have some different perspective on how you would approach that meeting if you were in my place. What are some good arguments I should bring to backup my decision in standing my feet against his request. Or also if you think I'm overreacting and should just let it go or it's not worth the fight or that I'm in the wrong, feel free to say so and why.

TLDR;
Another team manager wants me to switch a tool I use. He has no good argument to tell me why I should and I know for a fact it's just because he wants the entire company to work uniformly and when I asked "what is the issue of me using this" he did not provide any answer. Now we will all discuss it in a pointless bike-shedding meeting the situation. In the meeting there will be me, my direct manager, him and some random girl(?). How can I approach this meeting in terms of backing up my case?

Comment: I'm confused here, sounds like you're saying that you single-handedly make a decision to use a different tool than what the company uses and instructed you to use. But you want help to justify your lack of following instructions.

Comment: it wasn't an instruction in the sense of requirement. It was more in the sense "This is the tool these teams are using and we try to follow". Other bigger decisions like for example replacing an unfit backend and database setup for the project I consulted with my direct manager and explained why. In every single one he backed me up, but clearly he did not spend 5 minutes thinking on it as it was too technical/he was too busy, and he said many times "I trust your judgment". This one decision then I took it single-handedly cause it was a no-brainer: it only affects my work solely

Comment: @HugoHowarts How come you have a different name from OP but comment as if you were OP?

Comment: This is a rant. You should trim it down at least in half and focus it on your question. Anyway, it sounds like you are arrogant and have trouble working in teams.

Comment: You need to write a summary of this and be clear about what you expect.

Comment: lovely community! People clearly don't think this is a valid question and downvote it. That's fine. So I try to delete the question as it will lead nowhere, but then you can't delete it. So now just a wall  for people to come and make their own  judgment about a person they think they know based on a small context written with some frustration and call you arrogant and such. I even got mass downvoted in Stackoverflow questions that were inactive from 5 years ago. You can literally get better interactions in a reddit group. Outcome: meeting went fine and I got to keep using the tool I want

Comment: @HugoHowarts Don't worry: it's getting closed.

Answer (score 11):

Here's the thing:  The entire  rest of the company uses Tool A.  Even if you personally think  using Tool B makes you more productive, it:

- Makes your manager less productive by having to learn both tools A and B.
- Makes any internal transfers to  the team less productive by having to learn tool B
- If tool A is industry standard and tool B is not (which tends to be the case at larger companies; either they use more industry-standard tools or they use in-house tools for infosec concerns), then it makes hiring new people into your team more difficult because they have to learn tool B (there is a lesser chance they know it already).

If you want to convince your manager to use tool B instead of A, these are, in my opinion, the things you have the convince him of.  If you can't convince him of these things (either because you can't convince him or  they're not true), then you're not going to  do well:

1. That Tool B is more industry-standard than Tool A.  For  example,  Spring Data Mongo is more industry standard than using the native Java MongoDB driver (I  speak on this one in particular from experience).  Jira is more industry-standard than Asana (also from experience).  Git is more industry standard than SVN (not  from experience  on this one).   AWS more industry standard than IBM Cloud.  MongoDB more industry  standard than CockroachDB (this one I actually lost on for  other reasons even though it's true).  Industry standard tools are "proven", and managers like "proven", especially in large companies.  It helps to manage risk when you know your tool is "proven".  So  you're going to need to  show that the  tool is "proven".
2. That it will be easier to hire people for tool B than tool A.  This comes with the above, that  the more industry-standard a tool is,  the easier it is to hire people who know how to use  it.  This lowers the onboarding cost for new hires to your team.  Even if a tool is not industry-standard yet, if it is showing signs  of  replacing an existing tool, then this may work to  your benefit.  Think NodeJS  vs. Java,  or Java vs. C, or C vs. FORTRAN.  Once upon a time, those would have been industry standard, but then they got replaced.
3. That tool B does not have any external considerations that tool A does not have.  For  example, if tool B has a "personal edition" and a "professional edition",  it may be OK for the company to cheat and let you use the "personal edition" to do your work (even though it's technically illegal,  some companies do this if their staff/budget is small).  When  you have a growing team, this becomes less and less  feasible.  If it's an issue of  licensing and the company doesn't have (or want to  pay) the budget for licenses, then you're not getting your way.

These are  a few of the considerations you're going to have to   address if you want to be taken seriously.  If you can't  make the case in some  of these,  then you may just have to bow to your manager this time.

Comment: exactly.  "No good reason" is a really bad way to put it because there are a lot of really good reasons.

Answer (score 8):

**Manager wants to me to change methodoloy for no good reason and I don't accept it, so we will have a meeting about it. How should I proceed?**

You do it.

If you don't like following instructions you could consider being self-employed.

Comment: This  answer is not particularly helpful.  There are definitely cases, and they happen fairly often, where the manager institutes a policy that is blatantly stupid and it's useful for employees  to speak against such policies if they can provide  a  convincing and reasonable argument  to do so.   Simply  saying "just do whatever the manager says" leads to a lot of problems in many situations, in a general sense (perhaps not in this  specific instance, but that remains  to be seen).

Comment: This is not a policy question, this is about the work itself.

Answer (score 5):

Is this really about Tool A vs. Tool B or is this more a general problem with following instructions that don’t have a solid justification attached to them? No one likes having to do stuff they disagree with but that’s kind of the nature of the whole employer/employee relationship. It sounds like you’ve been given a good amount of decision-making freedom over your part of the product. If the choice of kahnbahn board is the most egregious encroachment on your autonomy, I’d consider that a pretty good deal.

Maybe the kahnbahn board really is *that* important in which case you’re welcome to disagree but everything in life is about compromise and there’s not a single person on the planet who doesn’t occasionally have to go along with things they don’t like so they can live to fight another day.

To answer your actual question, You’ve already said you’d be willing to leave the job if you don’t get your way so there’s not much left to talk about. Listen to his reasoning for why he wants you on Tool A. Explain why you think it’s better to continue with Tool B. If you’re still adamant and he refuses to budge, maybe try and see if there’s something else he’d be willing to compromise on. If you can’t reach an agreement, then you go your separate ways. (This seems crazy to me but it’s your life.)

Answer (score 4):

"The thing is...as I said, I have no problem in following orders, as long as it is something that makes sense."

You don't have the political pull to do whatever you want to. If you did then your manager would be asking you what to do. A CTO told me that when he joins a company it usually takes 2-3 years to get the CEO to actually change course and do things the way he says is best. There's no reason for you to expect your manager to salute you and do whatever you want.

Just start using the tool your manager wants you to. If he decides to switch it again in 2-3 months just roll with it. It happens.